# Spear Phishing attempt, how to respond?

Tags: phishing

I'm a software developer for a software development company responsible for multiple products, and I typically handle our IT needs as we're quite a small company. We had a suspicious incident today which looks an awful lot like spear phishing and I just wanted to know what actions we should be taking.

Today someone has called our office and claimed to be from Stanford University, stating that they wanted to invite our company to an online seminar for the benefit of students. They mentioned three staff members by name and job title (including myself), and asked to confirm our physical mailing address. When asked if they could mail us something through the post, I said yes and confirmed our address when it was read to me.

Immediately after this I received an email with no subject line from a Gmail address through my work address asking for my "direct number" and nothing else. It was also written in comic sans if that's relevant (we found it pretty funny).

He then called back and started asking one of our staff members for email addresses of the other two staff members who he mentioned by name. That staff member asked me through Slack for the addresses. By this time I had seen the email and figured it was a phishing attempt, so I told him to hang up immediately. It's been about 15 minutes and he has not called back since.

Was I wrong in my assessment that it was a phishing attempt? Are there any steps we should take to prevent a breach, beyond making it clear to all staff members to not share information that could be used to gain access to a staff members accounts? All our documents and software are internally hosted, we are currently preparing multiple patents and it would be potentially catastrophic if say our competitors got a copy of our technical design docs.

Comment: It certainly seems like phishy behaviour. It will be hard for us to determine what was going on without access to more data. Can you call Stanford and ask the manager of the seminar?

Comment: +1 to @schroeder said, in these cases its best to independently call Stanford and ask "I was contacted by someone who said they represented your university and I was wondering if I could verify their contact information and the online seminar they talked about", and most likely you'll be able to ascertain whether or not someone was claiming to be them or if the invitation was valid. And if it turns out to not be real I think they would be interested to know about such an incident.

Comment: OK thanks for the advice, I will call and ask Stanford directly. In the meantime, is there any advice on how to react to a phishing attempt?

Comment: In cases when you get an unexpected call, its better to tell them that you are going to contact them back (for any excuse). Ask for their contact information and first verify that the given phone number corresponds to the place they are saying. Then call that number and confirm their identity. Even if they show up in your door saying they are from the Police, etc, the same procedure should be followed to prevent being hustled. Its not an emergency after all, so its better to take some time to verify and be safe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there are a few guidelines:

1) **Filter** phishing mails at your company's mail server. This will already help a lot. Of course not so much against mentioned spear phishing where only few mails are sent to specific persons, but it might catch these as well.
2) If there is a phishing campaign, immediately counteract it by sending **awareness** mails.
3) Answer mails of questionable origin with attachments in a **safe environment** like Tails if you are not sure whether they might be authentic.
4) And most relevant for you: Don't give out internal mails randomly. If someone wants to contact some people inside of your company, he or she should just contact one person which then forwards the mail if necessary. There is a reason all companies have **one single point of contact**.

Phishing is done because it works and is hard to protect against. The safest way is to configure a mail server accordingly because that's the spot where all the mail traffic goes through, even the one intended for single persons. It is possible to analyze the incoming mails with simple scripts and alert people. For example a coworker in research and development is likely to have the same mail contacts again and again. Much similar to an Intrusion Detection System that works based on anomalies, an incoming mail from a stranger should be logged as a potential phishing attempt. This is, however, much harder to do for people working in customer service.

Comment: Thanks! We have since made sure everyone is aware of what happened and what to watch out for. We're a small company so this was pretty easy. I will look into a phishing filter for our mail server. Unfortunately I'm not in a position to tell people to not give out their emails, we all have business cards with our personal company email on them and this is how we tell people to get in touch.

Comment: As someone working with SMEs a lot, I think awareness is the cheapest solution every company can implement. There is a reason why evolution favoured gregarious animals, the ability to warn each other is a vital advantage.